# Adding 100 2D Arrays of different sizes (numpy)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is it possible to add two different sized arrays without broadcasting?

To my knowledge, broadcasting adds values to the smaller array in order to fill that space. But that would skew my results. I was wondering if there was some way to add two different sized arrays without having to compromise the values?

```
P = np.array([[1,2,3],[2,1,6],[7,9,1]])
L = np.array([[1,2],[4,1]])
```

output Looks like this:

```
P
1 2 3 
2 1 6
7 9 1

L
1 2  
4 1
```

It is important that the (diagonal) 1s in each square matrix align when adding two different sized matrices

How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe pad it with zeros and then add ( https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html )

Comment: Are you stacking or adding?

Comment: Broadcasting can add a leading dimension, and can change a size 1 dimension to something else.  It does not change a size 2 dimension to 3.  Broadcasting will do nothing with your 2 arrays.

Comment: So what result do you want?  `P+L` does not a clear meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
P + np.pad(L, (0,1), 'constant', constant_values=0)
```

So:

```
>>> P
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 1, 6],
       [7, 9, 1]])
>>> np.pad(L, (0,1), 'constant', constant_values=0)
array([[1, 2, 0],
       [4, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
>>> P + np.pad(L, (0,1), 'constant', constant_values=0)
array([[2, 4, 3],
       [6, 2, 6],
       [7, 9, 1]])
```

Comment: Why go to all the trouble when you can just add to a subset of P?

Comment: What trouble? @MadPhysicist

Comment: The fact that you make a copy of the smaller array. Seems wasteful.